# getting a following error,large data points,desired output-best fit to expt. data sets

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, fitting, warning-messages, nonlinear

I am trying to carry out list operation but running into a following error
I have large data sets(more than 0.2 million data points) and desired output will be a best fit (numerical data points ) to my experimental obtained data points. Please suggest any solution for following errors.

> Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {0.0164708,0.0164689,0.0164671,0.0164652,0.0164634,0.0164616,0.0164597,0.0164579,0.0164561,0.0164542,0.0164524,0.0164506,<<27>>,0.0163994,0.0163976,0.0163957,0.0163939,0.0163921,0.0163903,0.0163885,0.0163866,0.0163848,0.016383,0.0163812,<<224930>>}+{<<1>>}
>   cannot be combined.
>   Total::tllen: Lists of unequal length in ({-0.0164708,-0.016471,-0.0164712,-0.0164714,-0.0164715,-0.0164715,<<39>>,-0.0164303,-0.0164282,-0.016426,-0.0164238,-0.0164215,<<224929>>}+{<<1>>})^2 cannot be added.
>   How could I avoid it and what could be the reason of its manifestation?
>   code i m getting error in:

(* Final version *)

```
data = Import["F:\\text csv-160615\\6mw-2\\6mw-2.csv"];
Dimensions@data

data = Drop[data, {-1}];
datamean = Mean[data[[All, 2]]];

ti = 99.48;
tf = 1599.34;
dt = 2/300.;
ndsol1 = ParametricNDSolve[{y'[x] == -k1*y[x] - k2*y[x]*y[x] - 
     k3*y[x]*y[x]*y[x], y[ti] == 0.016470755}, 
  y, {x, ti, tf}, {k1, k2, k3}]

output = ParallelTable[
    ndsol2 = y[k1, k2, k3] /. ndsol1;
    mat = 
     Flatten@Table[Evaluate[ndsol2[x] /. ndsol1], {x, ti, tf, dt}];
    gendata = Transpose[{Range[ti, tf, dt], mat}];
    (*  Fitness test *)
    ssres = Total[(gendata[[All, 2]] - data[[All, 2]])^2];
    sstot = Total[(data[[All, 2]] - datamean)^2];
    r2 = 1 - (ssres/sstot);
    {k1, k2, k3, r2}, {k1, 0, 0, 0}, {k2, 1, 1.1, 0.1}, {k3, 1, 1.1, 
     0.1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
output = Flatten[output, 2];

pos = Ordering[output[[All, 4]], -1]
selvalues = Flatten@output[[pos]]

ndsol21 = y[selvalues[[1]], selvalues[[2]], selvalues[[3]]] /. ndsol1;
mat1 = Flatten@Table[Evaluate[ndsol21[x] /. ndsol1], {x, ti, tf, dt}];
gendata1 = Transpose[{Range[ti, tf, dt], mat1}];

output = Export["F:\\text csv-160615\\6mw-2\\6mw-2-op.xlsx", 
  gendata1[[1 ;; -1 ;; 10, All]]]
(*Plot[Evaluate[ndsol2[x]/.ndsol1],{x,80,1500}]*)

ListPlot[{gendata1, data}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Small], 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, -.002}]
```

Comment: This may be only a speculation, I think the problem manifests because you are trying to do something with two data sets of unequal lengths where the function you are applying requires them to be of equal lengths. Please post your code  so people can try and help you out

Comment: this error occurred for 5 data set out of 11.when i m changing t_f (last data point of x-axis ) to second last t_f-1, error is not coming for 3 out of 5 files.and completely clueless why is happening. change in x data points are same 2/300, but y data sets are experimental obtained data point.

Comment: so what is exactly meant by unequal legth?

Comment: i will post a code soon.

Comment: If you do `Length[a]` you get the length of the list. For certain operations the lengths of the lists need to be equal. For multiple dimension lists use `Dimensions[]`

Comment: in fact both x and y data sets are experimental vales with equal spacing in x data sets.

Comment: @avinash post a small snipet of your code which can be used to assess the problem. It would be useful if you could edit your original post to include some additional information like: code, small data sample and what is the desired output

Comment: Okay, but you know we can't access your `F:` drive right? So we still can't run your code.

Comment: can i send you data points excel sheet?

Comment: one which is giving error?

Comment: its 7.6MB excel file how can I share with you @Feyre?

Comment: http://www.tinyupload.com/
However, it is considered good form to always provide a MINIMAL example which still reproduces the problem.

Comment: I tried several ways like taking small part of data points from same file but stil error coming?

Comment: is other way to share file with you @Feyre?

Comment: tinyupload.com should work, it's what I use, you'd have to google for yourself if you can't use that.

Comment: avinash.warankar AT students.iiserpune.ac.in Please put @ at AT to avoid the spam emails. this is my email id. please send me your email since i am tinyupload is blocked at my institute @Feyre

Answer (score 1):

If the `data` has the dimensions `{n, 2}` where `n = Length[Range[ti, tf, dt]]` things should work fine.

Below is a minimal data set that has a length of 501.

```
ti = 100;
tf = 1600;
dt = 3.;

ndsol1 = ParametricNDSolve[{y'[x] == -k1*y[x] - k2*y[x]*y[x] - 
     k3*y[x]*y[x]*y[x], y[ti] == 0.016470755}, 
     y, {x, ti, tf}, {k1, k2, k3}]

junk = y[0, 1.05, 1.05] /. ndsol1;
junk2 = Flatten@Table[Evaluate[junk[x] /. ndsol1], {x, ti, tf, dt}];
data = Transpose[{Range[ti, tf, dt], junk2}];

Length[Range[ti, tf, dt]]
(* 501 *)

Dimensions@data
(* {501, 2} *)
```

Now invoke `ParallelTable`

```
output = ParallelTable[

  ndsol2 = y[k1, k2, k3] /. ndsol1;
  mat = Flatten@Table[Evaluate[ndsol2[x] /. ndsol1], {x, ti, tf, dt}];
  gendata = Transpose[{Range[ti, tf, dt], mat}];

  (*Fitness test*)
  ssres = Total[(gendata[[All, 2]] - data[[All, 2]])^2];
  sstot = Total[(data[[All, 2]] - datamean)^2];
  r2 = 1 - (ssres/sstot);

  {k1, k2, k3, r2},
  {k1, 0, 0, 0},
  {k2, 1, 1.1, 0.1},
  {k3, 1, 1.1, 0.1}
  ]

(* {{{{0, 1., 1., 0.998722}, {0, 1., 1.1, 0.998761}}, {{0, 1.1, 
    1., 0.998918}, {0, 1.1, 1.1, 0.998886}}}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an extended comment as @JackLaVigne and @e.doroskevic have already provided the answer.  Below is a process I use when I mess up and attempt to combine lists of unequal length.

The error shown is actually two errors:

> Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in
>   {0.0164708,0.0164689,0.0164671,0.0164652,0.0164634,0.0164616,0.0164597,0.0164579,0.0164561,0.0164542,0.0164524,0.0164506,<<27>>,0.0163994,0.0163976,0.0163957,0.0163939,0.0163921,0.0163903,0.0163885,0.0163866,0.0163848,0.016383,0.0163812,<<224930>>}+{<<1>>}
>   cannot be combined.
>
> Total::tllen: Lists of unequal length in
>   ({-0.0164708,-0.016471,-0.0164712,-0.0164714,-0.0164715,-0.0164715,<<39>>,-0.0164303,-0.0164282,-0.016426,-0.0164238,-0.0164215,<<224929>>}+{<<1>>})^2
>   cannot be added.

Each error is about the combining or adding of two lists and a compact version of the first list in each "bad" statement is shown.  The number of elements of that first list can be determined by counting the numbers shown and the "counts" given between << and >>:

```
23 + 27 + 224930 = 224980
```

and

```
11 + 39 + 224929 = 224929
```

We know that

```
ti = 99.48;
tf = 1599.34;
dt = 2/300.;
r = Range[ti, tf, dt], mat}];
Length[r]
```

results in a list with 224930 elements.  The first error must belong to

```
ssres = Total[(gendata[[All, 2]] - data[[All, 2]])^2];
```

and the second error is from

```
sstot = Total[(data[[All, 2]] - datamean)^2];
```

Therefore `gendata[[All,2]]` has 224930 elements and `data[[All,2]]` has just 224929 elements.

Maybe the last row of "F:\text csv-160615\6mw-2\6mw-2.csv" is not read in?